# C# show data between two dates in Datagridview. Dates from DatetimePicker or Textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2010, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am working on a code in C# where I used OLEDB connection string to connect MS access database. 
    I have a form where I show data from database in datagridview on some criteria.
Below are criteria:

a) Person (come from database in

b) Process (come from database in textbox)

c) From Date (Datetimepicker)

d) To Date (Datetimepicker)

Result what I want: first I select person and than process and than From Date and then To date and click on View Button. which should show data from MS-Access based on above criteria I selected.

I've tried below methods:

**Code:**
    1. For Person and Process filter:

```
        DataView DV = new DataView(dt1);
        DV.RowFilter = string.Format("[Person] LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox5.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
```

2. For Date Time between Two date I tried many and Google lots but not find answer. I tried below:

a)

```
        SqlConnection con = new 
        SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);
        string queryString = "";
        queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE dob BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, con);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox7.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@enddate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox8.Text;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        GridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

b)

```
        string FD = "";
        FD = dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        string TD = "";
        TD = dateTimePicker5.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        connection.Close();
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command123 = new OleDbCommand();
        command123.Connection = connection;
        string query123 = "select * from Table1 where [P Date] between date '"# + dateTimePicker4.Text.ToString() + #"' and date '"# + dateTimePicker5.Text.ToString() + #"'"
        command123.CommandText = query123;
        OleDbDataAdapter da123 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command123);
        DataTable dt123 = new DataTable();
        da123.Fill(dt123);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt123;
```

c)

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataView DV = new DataView(dt1);
        DV.RowFilter = string.Format("[P Date] >=" + textBox7.Text + " and <" + textBox8.Text + "");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
```

d)

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataView DV = new DataView(dt1);
        //DV.RowFilter = "[P Date] IN (#11/01/2019#, #11/11/2019#)";
        //DV.RowFilter = "[P Date] >=#"+dateTimePicker4.Text+"# and [P Date] <=#"+dateTimePicker5.Text+"#";
        //dataView.RowFilter = "Date IN (#12/31/2008#, #1/1/2009#)" // date time values
        //DV.RowFilter ="([P Date] >=CDate('dateTimePicker4.Text')) and ([P Date] <=CDate('dateTimePicker5.Text'))";
        //DV.RowFilter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, "([P Date]>=#{dateTimePicker4.text}#) and ([P Date] <=#{dateTimePicker5.Text}#)");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;

For connection I am trying OLEDB connection.

            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DatabasePath.accdb;
            Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
        connection.Close();
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
        command1.Connection = connection;
        //Select all column use belw query
        string query = "select * from Table1";
        command1.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        connection.Close();

this code is working but problem is that it shows all data not based on criteria based data.

I expect the output in Datagridview based on all criteria. Show only data which falls under all criteria.
```

Comment: Is the dob column in access a string or a datetime object?

Comment: @jdweng: No it is in DdMmyyy format. First it was in text but not getting result so changed to ddmmyyy. But not getting result.

Comment: How can you answer a A or B question with a NO answer?  I can not figure out your last response!!!

Comment: Sorry for confusion.. in database date column format was text but I did not get result so I changed it to DDMmYyy but unfortunately I did not get result. So currently date format is MMddyyy.

Comment: Changing the format just changes the display format when the cell is DateTime object (not a string).  If the column in database is a string you need to compare a string with a string (not a string with a DateTime, or a DateTime with a string).  You need to compare apples with apples, not apples with oranges.

Comment: Yes I got your point string to string date to date. But how ? What should be code.. because I tried many methods but not getting results.

Comment: You already have data in the database in string format.  You should have put the dates into the database as DateTime.  So you have two options 1) Fix the database and change from string to DateTime 2) Change your query.  Since you are comparing dates (between) you have to convert the string to a date in the query so the comparison will work.

Comment: As per your suggestions I did: I put the dates into the database as DateTime. still getting error. I am not getting proper code for comparing dates. I am new in C#.

Comment: Are you still use for comparison textBox7.Text?  You need to add a '#' for option 'b)'  (see : https://debradalgleish.com/blog/2017/08/26/access-query-date-criteria-examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you describing what's wrong with your results. If you are asking for a general help how to do it, here is one example. Bear in mind: The example is simple and does not use parametric query. That's up to you.

Converted C#

```
string wQueryCreated, wQueryChanged, wQueryCreatedBy, wQueryChandedBy;

if (this.fiCreated.Checked == true)
    wQueryCreated = " AND DateCreated >= '" + Format(this.dtpFiCreatedOd.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00") + "' AND DateCreated <= '" + Format(this.dtpFiCreatedDo.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd 23:59") + " ' ";
else
    wQueryCreated = "";

if (this.fiChanged.Checked == true)
    wQueryChanged = " AND DateModified BETWEEN '" + Format(this.dtpDateChangedFrom.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + Format(this.dtpDateChangedTo.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "' ";
else
    wQueryChanged = "";

if (this.fiCreatedBy.Checked == true)
    wQueryCreatedBy = " AND PersonCreatedBy = " + this.fiCreatedBy.SelectedValue + " ";
else
    wQueryCreatedBy = "";

if (this.fiChandedBy.Checked == true)
    wQueryChandedBy = " AND PersonModifiedBy = " + this.fiChandedBy.SelectedValue + " ";
else
    wQueryChandedBy = "";

// use query conditions in SELECT statement     
queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DateDeleted IS NULL " + wQueryCreated + wQueryChanged + wQueryCreatedBy + wQueryChandedBy + "; ";
```

Original VB.NET:

```
    Dim wQueryCreated, wQueryChanged, wQueryCreatedBy, wQueryChandedBy As String

    If Me.fiCreated.Checked = True Then  ' filter date created
        wQueryCreated = " AND DateCreated >= '" & Format(Me.dtpFiCreatedOd.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00") & "' AND DateCreated <= '" & Format(Me.dtpFiCreatedDo.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd 23:59") & " ' "
    else
        wQueryCreated = ""
    End If

    If Me.fiChanged.Checked = True Then  ' filter datechanged
        wQueryChanged = " AND DateModified BETWEEN '" & Format(Me.dtpDateChangedFrom.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND '" & Format(Me.dtpDateChangedTo.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' "
    else
        wQueryChanged = ""
    End If

    If Me.fiCreatedBy.Checked = True Then  ' filter chandged by person
        wQueryCreatedBy = " AND PersonCreatedBy = " & Me.fiCreatedBy.SelectedValue & " "
    else
        wQueryCreatedBy = ""
    End If

    If Me.fiChandedBy.Checked = True Then  ' filter modified by person
        wQueryChandedBy = " AND PersonModifiedBy = " & Me.fiChandedBy.SelectedValue & " "
    else
        wQueryChandedBy = ""
    End If

    ' use query conditions in SELECT statement      
    queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DateDeleted IS NULL " & wQueryCreated & wQueryChanged & wQueryCreatedBy & wQueryChandedBy & "; "
```

This examples uses 4 conditions, taking information from 6 fields in total (dtp prefixes mean `DateTimePicker`). Notice a bit different date handling between first and second condition, which do similar thing.

Also notice, that this method requires 1 fixed condition. It could be `1=1`, but obvously you usually use it like I did in the example, so i.e. to exclude soft-deleted rows (`DateDeleted IS NULL`). You need 1 fixed condition so that you don't have to care about the beginning `" AND "` in the rest of the conditions, regardless of their usage.

You can use "endless" conditions and combine them, even of a different data types. If you need to restrict to combination of conditions, validate they are filled in before you run the query. Obviously, you don't have to test for checked `CheckBoxes`, you can check for `ComboBox1.SelectedValue > -1` (something is selected in `ComboBox`), or `TextBox1.Text.Length >= 3` (at least 3 characters are entered into a `TextBox`), etc.

Comment: I am new in C# so I am unable to understand where I can use this all conditions.

Comment: Place all the code above into your function, where you fetch and load data into `DataGridView`. The last line is actually from your code, I just modified it to use the filters (once again, this is without parameters, it will work, but in exposed environment might be unsafe). Then next to every `IF`, modify the left part of teh condtion to point at your objects in your form and also on the 2nd line of every condition block, modify a control to whatever you have in your form to get correct filter string. Then it will work fine. Try it yourself how it works, if you still have trouble, let me know